# moving from ubuntu 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit

I have a all in one panel PC - Lenovo Ideacenter B300 with Ubuntu 13.10 (32 bit).

I also have the following mount setup:

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
....
​/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw)
....
```

I just found out that my PC actally has a 64 bit architecture (lscpu):

```
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

and so I would like to reinstall ubuntu 64bit GIVEN that I have my /home data on another partition. My question is:

Would the earlier installed (installed as ubuntu 32 bit) "/home" on another partition work fine when I reinstall Ubuntu 64 bit ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.
 It should work just fine.